In BluetoothLeScanner can not be resolved imports
Please help me resolve this problem.
My project can be compiled but there are arrors by importing the  libraries. Plese see Image below.
Phone Samsung galaxy S22 Ultra Android 14
BluetoothLeScanner.java
`   compileSdk = 34
minSdk = 24
targetSdk = 34
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`
dependencies {

implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
//    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.3")
//    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.3")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3")
implementation("androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0")
implementation("com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
//    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.8.3") // For Java
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1")
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1")
implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.8.2")
}

GradleVersion 8.0
I want to start Scan for BluetoothLeDeveces.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Updated Android Studio. Now is working fine.
